# Synchronous XMLHttprequest get NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 on Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, web

Safari is throwing an error and aborting synchronous XMLHttpRequest, if the request is taking more than 10 secs (approx) to process on the server. "NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101". Its working fine on all other browsers. Any workaround to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Any workaround? Sure. Don't misuse the XMLHttpRequest for synchronous requests ;)

Comment: I use it to do some server verification, then response to the client side.